# React Native Expo App Keeps Failing to Run Developer Mode?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native

I have manage to get it working using "@react-native-firebase/app" , "@react-native-firebase/auth" and then i try to reinstall the git on another device but for some reason when i try run `npx eas build` and selected **Android** then it builds sucessfully. for Some Reason it shows this error when i try run `npx expo start` in development build:

> CommandError: No development build (com.deme.myapp) for this project is installed. Please make and install a development build on the device first.

I have also imported from firebase on the **.plist** and **.json** files suggested into the correct places following the documentation on https://rnfirebase.io/.

**It was working yesterday and since I just done imported my git to another laptop it isn't I'm so confused.**

---

It just says this error:

This is my **app.json**:

```
    {
  "expo": {
    "name": "my-app",
    "slug": "my-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/logo.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.deme.myapp",
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/logo.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
        "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
      },
      "package": "com.deme.myapp"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "scheme": "my-app",
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      "@react-native-firebase/auth"
    ],

    "extra": {
      "router": {
        "origin": false
      },
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "{{HIDDEN FOR THREAD}}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**eas.json:**

```
{
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/analytics": "^0.10.0",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.9.23",
    "@firebase/auth": "^1.4.0",
    "@firebase/firestore": "^4.3.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.6.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.6.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-firebase": "^0.0.0-alpha.0",
    "expo-image": "~1.3.5",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-router": "^2.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
    "firebase": "^10.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: See [this related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75530990/eas-expo-creates-development-build-that-is-not-loading-the-app-but-production-a) for more info.  Have you tried running `npx expo start --dev-client`?  Good luck!

Comment: @HunterYavitz Yes i have that's when the error shows up

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled the project using `npx eas build --profile development --platform android` and it worked...